# Validating email addresses belongs to our domain

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-workspace

I want to use a Google Form to populate a Google Spreadsheet. One of the fields is email address, and I need to validate this against the list of emails for our organisation - in other words forcing people to use valid and existing email addresses.

Our organisation uses Google Apps. The form will be created by a user who is in our organisation and only email addresses from our organisation/domain will be considered valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the experimental Apps Script [Domain Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_domain) API. Here's how I'd do it.

```js
function isValidEmailInMyDomain(address) {
  var parts = address.split('@');
  if( parts.length != 2 )
    return false;
  if( parts[1] != UserManager.getDomain() )
    return false;
  try {
    UserManager.getUser(parts[0]);
    return true;
  } catch(doesNotExist) {
    return false;
  }
}

function testFunction() { //check the menu View > Logs
  Logger.log(isValidEmailInMyDomain('aEmailIn@yourDomain.com'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can this behaviour be triggered by a standard Google Form or does it have to one that is built using the Google App Scripts GUI tool?

Comment: Henrique's solution is great.  You can trigger it AFTER the form submission and e-mail the submitting user of any error by forcing the capture of their username or you need to build this Form as a UiApp instance.

Comment: @andyg1 yes, you can call it from a function triggered on form submit.

Comment: How would you use this to validate the form and have the user correct errors? I'm not really interested in emailing the user after accepting bad data.

Comment: @RichardBronosky that would be a Google Form feature, which is not available. Apps Script can only interact with Forms like the owner does, editing/etc and looking at it's responses. There's no changing how a live form behaviors.

Answer (score 13):

Now you can put a Regular Expresion in the field:

For EMAIL:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-\.]+
```

Answer (score 3):

**Email Address –** the regex below should match most common email address formats, including Gmail aliases that accept the “+” sign but there’s no perfect solution.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-\.]+
```

You can use like:

[image]

For More Regex: [Useful Regular Expressions for Validating Input in Google Forms](https://www.labnol.org/internet/regular-expressions-forms/28380/)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a script. Simply add a response validation to the question. In the first field, choose "text"; in the second field, "contains"; in the third field, "@'yourdomain'"- that's it!

Answer (score 0):

Modified answer [Romias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7720/romias)
(mail - min length 3, domain - min length 2)

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\+-]{3,}@[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,}\.[a-zA-Z0-9-\.]{2,}
// a@a.a = false 
// aaa@aa.aa = true
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not a Google Apps Script question, but when you create the form, you can select a check box that says "Automatically collect respondent's username. "

Comment: That's for the person filling it in. What I want is to validate a text field to check if what was entered was both a valid email address and was an email address for this organisation. This is why I thought it would be an Apps Script question.

Answer (score -2):

If you only want to validate if it's an email, there is a simple solution nowadays: add a response validation, select "Text" and "Email". That's all. :)

If you want to check if it's an e-mail from "yourcompany.com", you will need a regex. Select "Regular expression" - "Matches" and write: `[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\+-]+@yourcompany\.com`

Notice the "\" before the "." in "yourcompany.com". Regular expressions need this to avoid another meaning for the dot.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not enough: the string "`my email is abu@yourcompany.com`" is _not_ a valid email (although it contains the company validation string). So most typo errors would not be catched if you use a simple _Text - Contains_ solution

Comment: Ok, abu. In fact, "contains" is not enough. I edited again, to use regex and solve the problem.