# Prototyping a workflow app with Apps Script

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, serverless-framework, google-workspace

I want to prototype an app and I thought Apps Script could be a quick way to do this, but being new to Google toolset I need someone to put me in the right direction to figure what is available and what components I need to put together to get this working.

Here's what the app does:

1. I put in an order in a form on a web page. (Google Forms? App Script web app?)
2. Some inputs in the form are dynamically shown depending on previous inputs.
3. The inputs are validated.
4. There is a list of receivers with mobile numbers (Google Spreadsheets?)
5. When submitted, the order is sent to a web service (Twilio REST API) that sends SMS text messages to each of the receivers.
6. Before submitting I want to be able to see a preview of the generated text message and the total cost for sending SMS.
7. After submitting, the order is also logged (Spreadsheets?)
8. In the text message there is a link to a web page that is specific to that order for more details

I don't need specific code but I need to find out what to use for each step. Also any examples or samples that could help me on the way would be very useful.

**Update** - My specific question for now to get started is:

Is it possible to use Google Forms to have dynamic fields (entering data in one field defines next fields with their choices), custom validations (validations are more than regex and multiple fields are validated together) and previews (when entering data, show some live calculations)? If not, how can I use Apps Script with Html to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

So you might what to use a Google Form, I do not know what type of Order you are trying to do, but in my example I will be assuming that an order is some type of department work order that is submitted and you want it to send a txt message to "supervisors" so that they can review the work order.

Here is a poorly drawn overview of how I envision this.

[Overview Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVlL8.jpg)

### How I would Start

1. Create your form.

   - When you create a Google Form it automatically creates a Google Spreadsheet.
   - You are able to input validate the data on the form itself OR if you are really picky, you can validate the data on the spreadsheet itself with Formulas or even app script itself.

     - Here is a start on [setting rules on your form](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3378864?hl=en).
     - [Email validation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10654929/7947734)
     - [Advance Validation(Pretty much everything else)](https://www.labnol.org/internet/regular-expressions-forms/28380/)
   - you set responses to direct the form to different pages or sections of the form based on an answer.
     [Image With example on how to base questions on previous answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR807.png)
2. Prepare your spreadsheet

   - So you already have a sheet for your Form Submission. Lets make another Sheet for your receivers. This way you can edit your receivers mobile numbers so your App Script does all the heavy lifting by cycling through this sheet when sending the messages.
   - You can also add any other information you need
3. Google App Script

   - Ok, The fun part. Now you have code. This is where you can get everything else you want or need. I would first write a function that all it does is collect the receivers data from your receivers sheet. [Link to SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) I would recommend looking at the guide to get you situated on how things work in App Script.
   - The Second function would be the Twilio API. I have not written anything for Twilio yet but here is what I found that I would use to get started to send a message. Of cousre you will have to modify it to cycle through your recipients and anything else you would want to do. I think this [Post will be able to get the Twilio Door Open](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15804401/7947734)
   - [Here is also Twilios Documentation on sending SMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages)

I think that is plenty information for you to get a leaping start into this very interesting project you have. If you have any further questions please ask. If I don't know the answers I can definitely help point you in the right direction. 
You will first have to start this project before I can get into some detail.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks Erick for taking the time to put this on whiteboard and think it through to help me. So I'll start with a Form and see how it develops. :)

Comment: No Problem! This seems like a very use case scenario, when you get it all up and working, You should post how the final result came out! Also, If you want your post to come out of hold you should ask more concise questions about what you are trying to do.

 For Example: 1. I need to be able to create a dynamic form. How do I use Google Forms to have dynamic questions ?

Comment: If you get your post to be off hold others will be able to share their ideas and concepts.

Comment: I really had to give the whole picture of what I was trying to do to see if it was possible at all using App Script, but now that I know it is possible I can break it down into separate questions.

Comment: @orad: Thank you for asking this question, I have a similar problem but with email and multiple recipients.